# using lightbox that can open another file

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox

Now I have a lightbox that only can use to show its `<div>` in current file . Is it possible to use a lightbox to **show something from another file**.

This is where my lightbox linked to `<a id="list" href="?lightbox[width]=808&lightbox[height]=365#div_currentfile" class="lightbox">Change Password</a>`

and the example file I want to open up from my lightbox is test_lightbox.php

any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. Load your php file inside your div using **AJAX** call by providing the relative path of test_lightbox.php
2. Put an **IFrame** inside your div and load that .php file in IFrame.

**First method** is best if you are trying to load the php file from the same domain. If test_lightbox.php file is served from some other place, then **second method** is the right choice.

If you are not sure how to load, have a look in the following url. But without jQuery also you can acheive the result.
[jQuery Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)